# matplotlib: xaxis dates ValueError: format %y requires year >= 1900 on Windows

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am getting a cryptic error from pandas-matplotlib I don't understand.

If I have the following df:

```
     Agency   Gage_no       date  something flag     elev
0      USGS  12392500 1996-01-01      55.38    A  2055.38
1000   USGS  12392500 1998-09-27      60.10    A  2060.10
2000   USGS  12392500 2001-06-23      61.90    A  2061.90
3000   USGS  12392500 2004-03-19      51.63    A  2051.63
4000   USGS  12392500 2006-12-14      52.51    A  2052.51
5000   USGS  12392500 2009-09-09      62.23    A  2062.23
6000   USGS  12392500 2012-06-05      60.06    A  2060.06
7000   USGS  12392500 2015-03-02      52.06    A  2052.06
8000   USGS  12392500 2017-11-26      51.60    P  2051.60
```

I want to plot and use `matplotlib.dates` to format the x axis:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df.plot(x='date',y='elev', ax=ax)

years = dates.YearLocator(10,month=1,day=1)
years1=dates.YearLocator(5,month=1,day=1)
dfmt = dates.DateFormatter('%Y')
dfmt1 = dates.DateFormatter('%y')

[i.xaxis.set_major_locator(years) for i in fig.axes]
[i.xaxis.set_minor_locator(years1) for i in fig.axes]
[i.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dfmt) for i in fig.axes]
[i.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dfmt1) for i in fig.axes]
```

I am getting a traceback indicating I am trying to use the date `format='%y'` for dates before 1900.

```
Out[40]: [None]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\gdal_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py", line 501, in _draw_idle
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\gdal_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 388, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\gdal_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\gdal_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1709, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\gdal_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 135, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\gdal_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\gdal_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2645, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\gdal_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 135, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\gdal_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\gdal_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1204, in draw
    ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\gdal_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1089, in _update_ticks
    minor_labels = self.minor.formatter.format_ticks(minor_locs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\gdal_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 259, in format_ticks
    return [self(value, i) for i, value in enumerate(values)]
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\gdal_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 259, in <listcomp>
    return [self(value, i) for i, value in enumerate(values)]
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\gdal_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 608, in __call__
    return num2date(x, self.tz).strftime(self.fmt)
ValueError: format %y requires year >= 1900 on Windows
```

Why is this happening, when clearly my dates only go back to 1996?

If I use `ax.plot_date` instead of `df.plot`, the plot is rendered correctly.

Comment: df.plot is in general incompatible with matplotlib.dates locators/formatters. I gave explanations for that in other questions on that topic already.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest when did they become incompatible?  I have used pandas and date formats before. The example I provided works for the major format `%Y`, just fails on the minor format `%y`

Comment: It's always been like this. Pandas may use all kinds of units.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I usually do with dates, considering x and y are given

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

ax.plot_date(x =, y = )
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')) # format as you wish
ax.set_xticks(x)

plt.show()
```